# Método see() do Codeception com Yii2 não exibe todo o conteúdo da página

Tags: php, testes, tdd, bdd, yii2

Olá! Estou testando um sistema PHP(7.2.1) que usa o framework Yii2, e para isso, por padrão estou usando o codeception.

Ao escrever testes funcionais, vários métodos não estão funcionando da forma esperada. Entre eles o método see() que deveria buscar um texto passado como parametro, na página especificada.
No meu caso o método see() efetua a busca somente no menu lateral da aplicação e não na página como um todo.

Gostaria de ajuda para tentar resolver esse erro, já pesquisei na documentação do framework mas não consegui encontrar nada referente ao meu problema.

A seguir o código dos testes funcionais que escrevi e o erro exibido no console.

Classe de teste:

```
<?php

use app\models\Usuario;

class FirstTryLoginCest
{

    public function _before(\FunctionalTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnRoute('site/login');
    }

    public function submitFormSuccessfully(\FunctionalTester $I)
    {
        $I->submitForm('#login-form', [
            '#usuario-username' => 'Fulano',
            '#usuario-password' => '12345678'
        ]);
        $I->see('Mural');
    }

    public function internalLoginByInstance(\FunctionalTester $I)
    {
        $admin = \app\models\Usuario::findOne(33);
        $I->amLoggedInAs($admin);
        $I->amOnPage('gestor/mural');
        $I->see('Fulano');
    }

}
```

Erro exibido no console:

```
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.4.1
Powered by PHPUnit 7.1.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Functional Tests (2) -------------------------------------------------- 
✖ FirstTryLoginCest: Submit form successfully (0.14s)
✖ FirstTryLoginCest: Internal login by instance (0.07s)
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 

Unit Tests (0) -------------------------------------------------------- 
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 

Time: 464 ms, Memory: 16.00MB

There were 2 failures:

---------
1) FirstTryLoginCest: Submit form successfully
Test  tests/functional/FirstTryLoginCest.php:submitFormSuccessfully
Step  See "Mural"
Fail  Failed asserting that  on page /index-test.php?r=site%2Flogin
-->  Username cannot be blank. Password cannot be blank. Lembrar no 
próximo acesso Entrar Esqueci minha senha Copyright &COPY; 2018 Nome da 
empresa 
--> contains "Mural".

Scenario Steps:

3. $I->see("Mural") at tests/functional/FirstTryLoginCest.php:19
2. $I->submitForm("#login-form",{"#usuario- 
username":"Fulano","#usuario-password":"12345678"}) at 
tests/functional/FirstTryLoginCest.php:16
1. $I->amOnRoute("site/login") at 
tests/functional/FirstTryLoginCest.php:10


---------
2) FirstTryLoginCest: Internal login by instance
Test  tests/functional/FirstTryLoginCest.php:internalLoginByInstance
Step  See "Fulano"
Fail  Failed asserting that  on page /gestor/mural
-->  Toggle navigation Fulano Fulano Fulaninho Administrador 
Perfil Sair Fulano Gii Debug Same tools Gii Debug Level One Level Two 
Level Two Level Three Level Three Nome da empresa &COPY; 2018   Nome da 
empresa Software Versão 9.0 β string(1) "0" 
--> contains "Fulano".

Scenario Steps:

4. $I->see("Fulano") at tests/functional/FirstTryLoginCest.php:29
3. $I->amOnPage("gestor/mural") at 
tests/functional/FirstTryLoginCest.php:28
```

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Você está a testar sua página de *login* com uma classe de testes funcionais, mas o correto, segundo a documentação do *Codeception*, é que se use a classe de aceitação (*\AcceptanceTests*).

[**Exemplo do site:**](https://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage)

```
<?php
class BasicCest
{
    // test
    public function tryToTest(\AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage('/');
        $I->click('Login');
        $I->fillField('username', 'john');
        $I->fillField('password', 'coltrane');
        $I->click('Enter');
        $I->see('Hello, John');
        $I->seeInCurrentUrl('/account');
    }
}
```

**Fontes:**

- [Codeception Docs - Acceptance
  Testing](https://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests)
- [Codeception Docs - Advanced
  Usage](https://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage)

Comment: Sim, estou fazendo isso pois sucessivamente quero testar outras funcionalidades mais complexas. Por padrão já vem testes funcionais de login.